# Unable to construct json datatable for Google charts

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I've been stuck for quite some time on this problem now. I have looked around a lot but I can't seem to figure out the answer. See the link below for the reference on google developers.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam

I have this PHP script which pulls data from my DB and then builds the JSON.

My code is as follows :

```
<?php 

header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');//Include this header to make the requests cross-origin 
include 'dbconnect.php';//File for database connection


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

//Check if query GET parameters are defined 
if(isset($_GET['date1']) && isset($_GET['date2'])){

    $parm1=$_GET['date1'];    
    $parm2=$_GET['date2'];   
    //We build the metadata node of our json object with chart info / update time / chart title 
    //date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT+8');
    //$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    //$array['meta'][]=array('title'=>'Sales data for year'.$parm1.'-'.$parm2);
    //$array['meta'][]=array('LastUpdated'=>$date);
    //$array['meta'][]=array('Info'=>'This chart displays sales data on an annual basis');

    $array['data']['cols'][]=array('label'=>'2008','type' => 'number');
    $array['data']['cols'][]=array('label'=>'2009','type' => 'number');   



}else{    

    echo "No data available";

}

$sql = "CALL TEST('$parm1','$parm2');";
//We run the query, store all rows in an associative array, then json_encode it 
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $i = 0; 
    while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {

        $array['data']['rows'][]= array(
                            'c' => array( 
                               array('v'=>intval($row[$i]))
                           )); 

                           echo $row[1];                         
    $i++; 
    }

}else {
    echo "0 results";
}

//unset($array['data']['rows'][0]);
echo $_GET['callback'].'('.json_encode($array).')';
$conn->close();//We close the database connection here 

?>
```

The json output from this php script is as follows :

```
 {
    data: {
        cols: [{
            label: "2008",
            type: "number"
        }, {
            label: "2009",
            type: "number"
        }],
        rows: [{
            c: [{
                v: 3016207
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

My first problem is that in the `c` node, only one value is added, when there should be two `v:{object}`. The accepted format afaik should be in my particular case, two `v:{object}` nested in the `c:[array]`. I have a strong feeling that `json_encode()` is failing to build a complex JSON, but I've thrown much tougher stuff to it in the past and it worked. Can anyone help me ? Please :o

EDIT : The expected json format is :

```
{
    data: {
        cols: [{
            label: "2008",
            type: "number"
        }, {
            label: "2009",
            type: "number"
        }],
        rows: [{
            c: [{v: 3016207 },{v: 3000528}]
        }]
    }
}
```

My query is returning these :

```
+---------+---------+
|  2008   |  2009   |
+---------+---------+
| 3016207 | 3000528 |
+---------+---------+
```

So basically the second column's value is not being inserted :/

Comment: Why do you think there should be two values in `$data["rows"][0]["c"]` when you are clearly only adding one? Also, unless you have a whole lot of columns in your database, you're going to run out of values quickly. Occam's Razor suggests that `json_encode()` is not failing here.

Comment: Without knowing what the database returns, and your expected JSON format, nobody will be able to tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @miken32 Sorry about that. I edited my post to include these data. And yeah, there might be a huge amount of columns being returned since it's a dynamic pivot based on a date range. In that specific case tho, only 2 columns are being returned since I specified values between 2008 and 2009.

Comment: Why is the first part of the JSON fixed at 2008 and 2009? Are those values supposed to be taken from the name of the column?

Comment: Your expected JSON is not valid. You really want your `v` values to be nested one deeper for every column?

Comment: Yeah, they were supposed to, I hardcoded them here just to make sure they were being generated properly so that I could focus on the rows problem. And regarding the nesting thing, no, my bad, it shouldn't be nested one deeper. (Edited again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoever came up with that JSON format should be fired. Looks like someone was trying on purpose to make things difficult.

But it's not hard to generate if you understand what the database function return values are and how to manipulate those arrays. For example: you were looping over your result set, even though it always has a single row, but you had no loop over the columns. Then you were trying to fill in your `c` element with a single value `$row[$i]` and wondering why it was only a single value. (I suspect you may be misunderstanding how the `$var[]` construct works.) Read up on these functions if you want to have success in this. You're still vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, by the way.

Anyway, this is obviously untested but should at least get you started.

```
$sql = "CALL TEST('$parm1','$parm2')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    foreach ($row as $name=>$val) {
        $array['data']['cols'][] = array('label'=>$name, 'type'=>'number');
        $c[] = array("v"=>$val);
    }
    $array['data']['rows'] = array(array('c'=>$c));
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I think that they came up with this format to have a standard json format for their function which takes a json object as a parameter. At least they know exactly where the keys are and what they are called :) Thank you for helping me understand the $var[] construct better :)